# SFINAE/requires based on static constexpr variable

Tags: c++

I was trying to understand some advanced SFINAE usage and how to replace it with concepts moving forward and hit this example:

```cpp
    struct A {
        static constexpr bool is_open = false;
        using T = void;
    
        // let us try some sfinae
        template<typename = std::enable_if_t<is_open>, typename...>
        void f(T& t) {}
    
        // maybe it needs to be a local parameter for sfinae to kick in?
        template<bool io = is_open, typename = std::enable_if_t<io>, typename...>
        void f(T& t) {}

        // let us try a constraint    
        template<typename...> requires is_open
        void f(T& t) {}

        // maybe the static member is the issue? let us hardcode
        template<typename...> requires false
        void f(T& t) {}

        // maybe the boolean is the issue?    
        template<typename...> requires (
            uint8_t(is_open) != 0
        )
        void f(T& t) {}
    
        // maybe it has to depend on some immediate template parameter?
        template<typename... Args> requires (
            uint8_t(is_open) * (sizeof...(Args)+1) != 0
        )
        void f(T& t) {}
    };
```

I'm trying to enable/disable a function based on some property of the type. None of the above functions actually works the way I expected and throws a compile error every time because of the `void&` substitution failure.

The only way I could make it work is:

```cpp
    template<typename LT = T, typename... Args>
    void f(LT& t) {}
```

but this has its own issues w.r.t the broader problem I'm solving (essentially, it's only checking if `T` is substitutable and ignoring the `is_open` member) and IMO is besides the point since I think `typename LT = T` is a hack in the first place.

Is it possible to somehow either not error out on substitution (what I thought the point of SFINAE was) or not substitute in the first place (what I thought the point of requires was) based on `is_open` only instead of `T`?

Comment: `void f(void& t)` is invalid...

Comment: *"because of the `void&` substitution failure"*. it is not an subtitution, `T` is not a template parameter of the function.

Comment: `is_open` is also non-template dependent,  With `template <typename T> class A { static constexpr bool is_open = !std::is_same<void, T>::value; /*...*/}`, you might use concept on those. SFINAE requires the template type come from function (even if defaulted from class one).